# How does FLIR embed multiple images into their thermal image results?

Tags: images, jpeg, layers

FLIR thermal cameras store results in .jpg files as read by the system and any viewer as a single layer image with all data visible.

The layers are principly: the thermal image in its resolution, a RGB image of the same scene, and an overlay of the colour scale of the image.

While image viewers all take the data as a fixed overlay, FLIR's bespoke data analysis tool extracts the layers for separate use. How?

Answer (score 2):

> FLIR® thermal cameras like the FLIR ONE® include both a thermal and a visual light camera. The latter is used to enhance the thermal image using an edge detector. The resulting image is saved as a jpg image but **both the original visual image and the raw thermal sensor data are embedded in the jpg metadata**

From:

- https://pypi.org/project/flirimageextractor/
- https://github.com/fclairec/FlirImageExtractor
- https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=9908.0

https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata
Metadata is data about data. Much like a library catalog is a list of all the books in a library. Digital image files keep metadata commonly about camera type, location, or in this case thermal or optical sub-images

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif